# How can I create a child to correspond to the text of a UITableView cell?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a teacher review application for my school, and the way I have it set up is that you pick a professor from the table view and it takes you to a new page where you can read and write reviews. For now, I have

```
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref?.child("Reviews").childByAutoId().setValue(myTextView.text)
}
```

Of course this creates a "Reviews" child, and that each professor profile reads from the same child and they all have the same reviews on their profile pages. How can I change "reviews" to the professor names in the table view so each child can be a different name?

Answer (score 0):

if your json in firebase it's like that

```
teacher_id
   -> name_teacher
   -> reviews
       ->id_review
       ->comment
```

his way every time you add a comment to a teacher you must add a different one, because the comment_id is autoId

Check the structure of your json, can you modify your question by adding more details?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

It's usually best practice to disassociate your keys from the data they contain; imagine if your teachers name was miss_vernard and she gets married and becomes miss_french. You would have to totally delete and recreate that node with the new name and any references to it would also have to change. Best bet is to use unique and separate key names.

Let's take a look at what your code does:

> ref = Database.database().reference()
>   ref?.child("Reviews").childByAutoId().setValue(myTextView.text)

If you run it twice, your Firebase will look like this:

```
root
  Reviews
    -YHijiaiiiid: "some name"
    -Ykjnnsi9njs: "another name"
```

What you probably want is

```
root
  Teachers
     -YHijiaiiiid
        teacher_name: "some name"
        reviews:
          -Yjjajsdasdd
             review: "best teacher evah"
          -Y900iosoo98
             review: "he learned me gooder"
     -Ykjnnsi9njs:
        teacher_name: "another name"
        reviews....
```

the code to get you going is similar to yours. This can be shortened once you get familiar with the flow:

```
ref = Database.database().reference() 
thisTeacherRef.child("Teachers").childByAutoId() //this is a child node within Teachers

theTeacherRef.child("teacher_name").setValue("some name")

thisTeacherReviewRef = thisTeacherRef.child("reviews").childByAutoId() //first review
thisTeacherReviewRef.child("review").setValue("best teacher evah")

thisTeacherReviewRef = thisTeacherRef.child("reviews").childByAutoId() //second review
thisTeacherReviewRef.child("review").setValue("he learned my gooder")
```